# Need info on Azure AD Authentication for on Prem App

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to Authenticate user from Azure AD for an on prem App. I am using Open ID connect for the same and using AzureAd options for the same. I am able to authenticate user but I am getting ID_Token when my user is authenticated. I am fine so far. But this ID_Token is valid only for 60 minutes (and don't want to increase this).

Is there a way I can refresh ID_Token without prompting user to sign in again; (I know we can refresh with Access Token but question is for ID_Token) may be JS which will auto refresh ID_Token and persist in cookies so that user will not sign out.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, AAD does **not support** refreshing the ID token because an id_token represents user authentication, information that cannot be refreshed without the user present. If you want to refresh an id_token, we can just re-authenticate for the id_token.

The maximum lifetime of id_token is one day. You could change the default time with Powershell, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/configure-token-lifetimes).

[image]

To get started:

1.Download the latest [Azure AD PowerShell Module Public Preview release](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureADPreview/2.0.2.129).

2.Run the Connect command to sign in to your Azure AD admin account. Run this command each time you start a new session:

```
Connect-AzureAD -Confirm
```

3.To create the policy, run the following command:

```
New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @('{"TokenLifetimePolicy":{"Version":1,"MaxInactiveTime":"14.00:00:00","MaxAgeSingleFactor":"90.00:00:00","MaxAgeMultiFactor":"90.00:00:00","MaxAgeSessionSingleFactor":"until-revoked","MaxAgeSessionMultiFactor":"until-revoked"}}') -DisplayName "OrganizationDefaultPolicyScenario" -IsOrganizationDefault $true -Type "TokenLifetimePolicy"
```

Another, you could try to authenticate user with access_token using [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow).

Comment: Thank you @Pamela that explains me well. 
But With Auth Code flow how can I just keep my authentication considering I don't have any other API or resource to access. My Current ID Token which I am getting on authentication is valid for 60 mins, so user will be promted to sign in again after 60 mins. Is there a way I can prompt user something like a pop up which says 'Click to continue your session' and if user clicks Ok then the session extends for another 60 mins?

Comment: The access_token is also expired after the default lifetime, but you could renew it with refresh token.  It seems you could get the id_token using username and password when clicking 'Click to continue your session'. Please refer to the [ROPC flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc), note to see the Important in the article.